# Raspberry Pi Openthread IPv6 Network

Tags: ipv6

I have set up a Raspberry Pi with an OpenThread RadioCoprocessor to run as a OpenThread Border router. This works, but I am having trouble reaching the NAT64 interface from the Thread network.

At home, I have a router which created a local IPv6 network. The Pi gets assigned two IPv6 ip address, and the routes to these addresses propagate to the RadioCoprocessor. Here I can add routes to the well-known-prefix and the NAT64 interface and use the NAT64 interface as DNS Server to resolve hostnames to well-known-prefix addresses and ping these addresses.

However at work, the local network does not have IPv6. The Pi does not get assigned a IPv6 address. At work I am unable to ping any well-known-prefix addresses from the OpenThread network, but I am able to ping from the Pi.

Am I missing a route?

Routing table at Home

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route -6 -n
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
::1/128                        ::                         U    256 3     0 lo
64:ff9b::/96                   ::                         U    1024 1     0 nat64
2002:1111:1111:1111::/64       ::                         UAe  256 1     0 eth0  <<< Router ipv6 network
fd11:db8:1::/64                ::                         U    256 1     0 otbr0
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75::/64       ::                         U    256 2     0 wpan0
fdaa:bb:1::2/128               ::                         U    256 3     0 nat64
fdb5:d386:5ef5::/64            ::                         UAe  256 1     0 eth0  <<< Router ipv6 network
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471::/64       ::                         U    256 2     0 wpan0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 2     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 nat64
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 wpan0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 otbr0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 vethdbec410
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 docker0
::/0                           fe80::ee3e:b3ff:fe63:1320  UGDAe 1024 1     0 eth0
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   7     0 lo
2002:1111:1111:1111::/128      ::                         Un   0   3     0 eth0   <<< Router ipv6 network
2002:1111:1111:1111:ba27:ebff:fe6f:9215/128 ::  <<< Router ipv6 network
 Un   0   3     0 eth0
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75::/128      ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75:a9c8:521f:d197:eca5/128 ::
 Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdaa:bb:1::2/128               ::                         Un   0   4     0 nat64
fdb5:d386:5ef5::/128           ::                         Un   0   3     0 eth0  <<< Router ipv6 network
fdb5:d386:5ef5:0:ba27:ebff:fe6f:9215/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 eth0  <<< Router ipv6 network
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471::/128      ::                         Un   0   6     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:e800/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc00/128 ::                         Un   0   4     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc10/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc11/128 ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc38/128 ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:f21d:c077:3438:5937/128 ::
 Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   6     0 eth0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 nat64
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 vethdbec410
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 docker0
fe80::42:23ff:fee8:b3c/128     ::                         Un   0   2     0 docker0
fe80::858:1860:afaa:fde9/128   ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fe80::3024:2fff:fe63:1c/128    ::                         Un   0   2     0 vethdbec410
fe80::3cd7:afb4:fc53:bc71/128  ::                         Un   0   3     0 nat64
fe80::ba27:ebff:fe6f:9215/128  ::                         Un   0   4     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 7     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 1     0 nat64
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 1     0 wpan0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 vethdbec410
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 docker0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     0 lo
```

Routing table at Work

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route -6 -n
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
::1/128                        ::                         U    256 2     0 lo
64:ff9b::/96                   ::                         U    1024 1     0 nat64
fd11:db8:1::/64                ::                         U    256 1     0 otbr0
fdaa:bb:1::2/128               ::                         U    256 3     0 nat64
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471::/64       ::                         U    256 2     0 wpan0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 2     0 wlan0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 nat64
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 wpan0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 otbr0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 veth89bb918
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 docker0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     0 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   5     0 lo
fdaa:bb:1::2/128               ::                         Un   0   5     0 nat64
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471::/128      ::                         Un   0   5     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:e800/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc00/128 ::                         Un   0   4     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc10/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc11/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc38/128 ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:f21d:c077:3438:5937/128 ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   8     0 wlan0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 nat64
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 docker0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 veth89bb918
fe80::42:7dff:fece:4ad4/128    ::                         Un   0   2     0 docker0
fe80::858:1860:afaa:fde9/128   ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fe80::1450:5aff:feb6:879f/128  ::                         Un   0   2     0 veth89bb918
fe80::5227:2e50:3570:ab37/128  ::                         Un   0   2     0 nat64
fe80::ba27:ebff:fe3a:c740/128  ::                         Un   0   2     0 wlan0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 7     0 wlan0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 1     0 nat64
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 1     0 wpan0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 veth89bb918
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 docker0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     0 lo
```

**Update**

I was missing the default route from the OT-RCP to the eth/wlan interface on the Pi.

I manually added an IPv6 address and added a default route with: "prefix add 2001:470:6c92:1::/64 paros med"

Now I can ping the NAT64 at FDAA:BB:1::2 But resolving DNS gives me an error 8 with description Security.

**Update 2**
tcpdump logs:

```
tcpdump: listening on wpan0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), snapshot length 262144 bytes

***DNS request from ot-cli thread device "ot dns resolve ing.nl fdaa:bb:1::2 53 1000 2 1"***
19:54:30.284814 IP6 (hlim 64, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 32) 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed.49153 > fdaa:bb:1::2.53: [udp sum ok] 11238+ AAAA? ing.nl. (24)
19:54:30.285478 IP6 (flowlabel 0x3bd7d, hlim 64, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 32) fdaa:bb:1::2.53 > 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed.49153: [udp sum ok] 11238 Refused- 0/0/0 (24)
19:54:30.302290 IP6 (hlim 64, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 32) 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed.49153 > fdaa:bb:1::2.53: [udp sum ok] 34254+ A? ing.nl. (24)
19:54:30.303347 IP6 (flowlabel 0x3bd7d, hlim 64, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 32) fdaa:bb:1::2.53 > 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed.49153: [udp sum ok] 34254 Refused- 0/0/0 (24)

***Successful Ping from ot-cli thread device "ot ping 64:ff9b::9765:818c"***
20:51:46.076737 IP6 (hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed > 64:ff9b::9765:818c: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 6, seq 6
20:51:46.088699 IP6 (hlim 56, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) 64:ff9b::9765:818c > 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 6, seq 6

***Successful Ping from ot-cli thread device "ot ping fdaa:bb:1::2"***
20:53:27.162740 IP6 (hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed > fdaa:bb:1::2: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 7, seq 7
20:53:27.162871 IP6 (flowlabel 0x9a0cc, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) fdaa:bb:1::2 > 2001:470:6c92:1:8196:1c3f:41ed:fed: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 7, seq 7
```

Comment: I was missing the default route from the OT-RCP to the eth/wlan interface on the Pi.
Added a default route with "prefix add 2001:470:6c92:1::/64 paros med"
Now I can ping the NAT64 at FDAA:BB:1::2 Resolving DNS gives me an error 8 with description Security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by dns setting in dhcpcd.conf

Network information

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:6f:92:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:3a:c7:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.119/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 86063sec preferred_lft 75263sec
    inet6 2001:470:6c92:1::1/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20b4:b0a4:1951:1a51/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: nat64: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.255.1/32 scope global nat64
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdaa:bb:1::2/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::541e:2c1c:3682:1f26/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: otbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:c0:8f:82:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global otbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd11:db8:1::1/64 scope global tentative
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link tentative
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:8a:3b:6f:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:8aff:fe3b:6f9a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vethe2fc65a@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 46:fe:f5:19:50:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.151.160/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute vethe2fc65a
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::44fe:f5ff:fe19:50bd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: wpan0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/void
    inet6 fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75:a9c8:521f:d197:eca5/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc11/64 scope global nodad deprecated
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc10/64 scope global nodad deprecated
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc38/64 scope global nodad deprecated
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc00/64 scope global nodad deprecated
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:e800/64 scope global nodad deprecated
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:f21d:c077:3438:5937/64 scope global nodad deprecated
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fe80::858:1860:afaa:fde9/64 scope link nodad
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route -6 -n
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
::1/128                        ::                         U    256 3     0 lo
64:ff9b::/96                   ::                         U    1024 4     0 nat64
2001:470:6c92:1::/64           ::                         U    303 1     0 wlan0
fd11:db8:1::/64                ::                         U    256 3     0 otbr0
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75::/64       ::                         U    215 3     0 wpan0
fdaa:bb:1::2/128               ::                         U    256 3     0 nat64
fdaa:bb:1::2/128               ::                         U    1024 1     0 nat64
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471::/64       ::                         U    256 1     0 wpan0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 nat64
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 otbr0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 vethe2fc65a
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 docker0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 wpan0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 wlan0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     0 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   7     0 lo
2001:470:6c92:1::/128          ::                         Un   0   3     0 wlan0
2001:470:6c92:1::1/128         ::                         Un   0   3     0 wlan0
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75::/128      ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75:a9c8:521f:d197:eca5/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdaa:bb:1::2/128               ::                         Un   0   9     0 nat64
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471::/128      ::                         Un   0   5     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:e800/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc00/128 ::                         Un   0   4     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc10/128 ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc11/128 ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc38/128 ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:f21d:c077:3438:5937/128 ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   8     0 nat64
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 vethe2fc65a
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 docker0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 wpan0
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   3     0 wlan0
fe80::42:8aff:fe3b:6f9a/128    ::                         Un   0   2     0 docker0
fe80::858:1860:afaa:fde9/128   ::                         Un   0   2     0 wpan0
fe80::20b4:b0a4:1951:1a51/128  ::                         Un   0   2     0 wlan0
fe80::44fe:f5ff:fe19:50bd/128  ::                         Un   0   2     0 vethe2fc65a
fe80::541e:2c1c:3682:1f26/128  ::                         Un   0   3     0 nat64
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 1     0 nat64
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 vethe2fc65a
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 docker0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 4     0 wpan0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 4     0 wlan0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     0 lo
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
64:ff9b::/96 dev nat64 metric 1024 pref medium
2001:470:6c92:1::/64 dev wlan0 metric 303 pref medium
fd11:db8:1::/64 dev otbr0 proto kernel metric 256 linkdown pref medium
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75::/64 dev wpan0 metric 215 pref medium
fdaa:bb:1::2 dev nat64 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fdaa:bb:1::2 dev nat64 metric 1024 pref medium
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471::/64 dev wpan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev nat64 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev otbr0 proto kernel metric 256 linkdown pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vethe2fc65a proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wpan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ot-ctl
> route
64:ff9b:0:0:0:0::/96 s med e800
fdaa:bb:1:0:0:0::/96 s med e800
Done
> prefix
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75::/64 paos med e800
Done
> ipaddr
fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75:a9c8:521f:d197:eca5
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc11
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc10
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc38
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:fc00
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:0:ff:fe00:e800
fdbb:9fbb:e58b:f471:f21d:c077:3438:5937
fe80:0:0:0:858:1860:afaa:fde9
Done
>
```

contents of /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
4# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.2.1/30

interface wlan0
#static ip_address=192.168.2.1/30
static ip6_address=2001:470:6c92:1::1/64
# dont set dns here
#static domain_name_servers=fdaa:bb:1::2

interface wpan0
static ip6_address=fd35:ad25:a99f:8c75:a9c8:521f:d197:eca5/64
```